# How to embed multiple resources into a satellite assembly?

Tags: c#, batch-file, localization

I want to script a re-usable batch file which can embed multiple .resources files from the current folder into a .DLL. So something along the lines of:

> al /target:lib /embed:XXX /embed:YYY /embed:ZZZ /culture:ru-RU /out:Name.Space.resources.dll /keyfile:key.snk /version:4.0.0.0

My problem is that I can't figure out how to place a list of files XXX,YYY,ZZZ into the AL.EXE command using a batch file. The best I can do is list the filenames in the current folder with the prefix "/embed:".

> @echo off
>   for %%i in (*.resources) do echo|set /p=/embed:%%i